# Toggle div visibility in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

AIM: To show the div when an icon is clicked once and hide if clicked again.

Problem: Keep getting this error I've changed it and still wasn't working.

```
  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
 'isHidden' is not defined
```

**P.S very new to react and react hooks**

This is what I've done I have no clue what to do at this point, please point out the problems and help me solve this it will be greatly appreciated.

```
    const [bar, setBar] = useState(()=> {isHidden: true});
    function toggleHidden(){
        setBar(prevBar =>{
            return {bar: !isHidden}
        })
    }
```

Comment: What is isHidden?

Comment: Try this
https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-show-hide-using-hooks-wbh7m?from-embed

Comment: @NaveenDA thanks a lot it worked plus i didn't know that I was suppose to put {} brackets around the element I wanted to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a React example using your code. Comments describe the changes I've made.

```js
const {useState} = React;

function Example() {

    // Just simply set the state with an object
    const [bar, setBar] = useState({ isHidden: false });
    
    function toggleHidden() {

      // Then set the state to the opposite of 
      // what it currently is in your toggle function
      setBar({ isHidden: !bar.isHidden });
    }

    // Now simply set the visibilty based on the state
    const style = { visibility: bar.isHidden ? 'hidden' : 'visible' };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={style}>Showing</div>
      <button onClick={toggleHidden}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `useState(()=> {isHidden: true});` to `useState(()=> ({ isHidden: true }));`. Notice the parentheses. Same thing in toggleHidden function, you have to add parenthesis around the object that you are returning, otherwise the `{` bracket is interpreted as the start of a function. Also, inside your toggleHidden function, you have to use prevBar to change the state i.e. `setBar(prevBar => ({ isHidden: !prevBar.isHidden }));`

Answer (score 0):

```
const [bar, setBar] = useState({isHidden : true});
function toggleHidden(){
    setBar(prevBar => !prevBar.isHidden)
}
```

Instead of passing a function to setBar pass the object. like in my example. state is just a value setState is the only thing that should be a function